# Pycharm HTML syntax colour coded not working

Tags: django, pycharm

Been following a tutorial on Youtube about building an app on Django. In pictures below you can see in his IDE that the same piece of HTML code is formatted, and I think this is why I'm running into issues when running my server. Anyone know how to fix this please?

The code on the tutorial:
[image]

My version:
[image]

Would be really grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to colour format the code, do the following steps and set your template format under the settings.

Visit:

On Unix based os:

> Preference->Editor->Color Scheme->Django Template

On windows:

> Setting->Editor->Color Scheme->Django Template

There you can select the colour schemes you like and you can also manually set the desired colours for tags, keyword, etc.

Also note that on dark mode, colour formatting is different from the light mode. You should try a dark mode if you want to achieve the exact colour settings.